# LGHT0094: Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixComponentGroup:Product.Generated' in section 'Product:*'

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm having this error on one of build servers. All other servers build it ok. Any ideas what can be wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also had this error, It seems to be a new thing automatically generated from Wix when a new setup is created. Wix did not like it when I upgraded from 3.5 to 3.6, i simply deleted it.

Comment: Just in case it helps anyone in the future - I had this when the component's id attribute was incorrect

Comment: Well, we just upgraded from WIX 3.5 to 3.8 and hit this issue. We either had to rewrite our wixproj and wxs files to avoid harvesting, or just use the answer @goodbuoy [provided](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12741595/1584012)

Answer (score 50):

Its a wix 3.6 issue.  Found the solution [here](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/How-to-get-heat-exe-to-harvest-td7473250.html).  All you need to do is add the following property *<EnableProjectHarvesting>True</EnableProjectHarvesting>* on your wix project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <EnableProjectHarvesting>True</EnableProjectHarvesting>
```

Comment: This worked for me. If I had a choice I would not use WIX. Upgrade Path Microsoft!? It would be so good if the documentation was better.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I should use `ComponentRef` instead of `ComponentGroupRef`

Comment: Man, seriously. I just spent half and hour for this BS. Who tf codes those error messages in WIX?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was getting the same error number:

*file_name.wxs(38): error LGHT0094: Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixComponentGroup:Name_of_the_ComponentGroup*

This was because I had moved the ComponentGroup to a different file, and the build script (cmake in my case, maybe you use ant) that calls candle.exe had not been updated to include the .wxs file that now contained the ComponentGroup.

Updating the cmake script to include the new file fixed the error. And the error message was actually meaningful, since this was an unresolved reference.

Answer (score 1):

After an upgrade from `Wix 3.5` to `Wix 3.8`, we got the same issue. However, we do not want project harvesting, so setting `EnableProjectHarvesting` to true is not a good solution. So to solve the problem, we had to change a couple things :

In the file `Product.wxs`, we removed completely the following line (from the attribute `<Feature>`) :

```
<ComponentGroupRef Id="Product.Generated" />
```

After that, in our `.wixproj`, we updated the `LinkerBaseInputPaths` to a `DefineConstants`.

So this means change

```
<LinkerBaseInputPaths>%(ProjectReference.RootDir)%(ProjectReference.Directory)obj\$(Configuration)\Package\PackageTmp\</LinkerBaseInputPaths>
```

To *(And please also notice the addition of `BasePath=%`)*

```
<DefineConstants>BasePath=%(ProjectReference.RootDir)%(ProjectReference.Directory)obj\$(Configuration)\Package\PackageTmp\</DefineConstants>
```

and finally we added

```
PreprocessorVariable="var.BasePath"
```

to our `HeatDirectory` attribute (which is just below the PropertyGroup we modified in the previous step).