# wix 3.6 ComponentGroupRef Id="Product.Generated" gives error, wix 3.5 does not

Tags: wix, wix3.6

I just updated wix to 3.6 and after the upgrade my wix project failed to build.

The following line in the xml triggers the error:

```
<ComponentGroupRef Id="Product.Generated"/>
```

The error explanation is the following:

```
error LGHT0094: Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixComponentGroup:Product.Generated' in section 'Product:*'.
```

If I comment out the  ComponetGroupRef element, the msi is created without any errors and it seems to work just as before the upgrade to 3.6.

Fails:

```
<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="My.net Server" Level="1">
   <ComponentRef Id="My.Server" />
   <ComponentRef Id="My.Server.exe.config"/>
   <!-- Note: The following ComponentGroupRef is required to pull in generated authoring from project references. -->
   <ComponentGroupRef Id="Product.Generated" />
</Feature>
```

Works:

```
<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="My.net Server" Level="1">
   <ComponentRef Id="My.Server" />
   <ComponentRef Id="My.Server.exe.config"/>
</Feature>
```

Could anyone shed some light on this error?  Am I breaking something that I should be aware of or fix?  How important is that entry and what exactly does it do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exact same question posted today, [LGHT0094: Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixComponentGroup:Product.Generated' in section 'Product:*'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386211/lght0094-unresolved-reference-to-symbol-wixcomponentgroupproduct-generated-i/12386738#12386738) You should search before asking a question, apologies came across a little rude there, was in a rush. Always good just to do a quick search before posting, it will prevent downvoting..:)

Comment: I have searched plenty in google and also here on stack exchange, so we must have just crossed paths.  Also, you have only come to more or less the same conclusions as me in your other answer, that deleting it seems to not break anything.  I was hoping for someone to shed some light on what is actually happening.

Comment: Marking this as answer, as at least the other question seems to have an answer that has helped some people.